# ElasticSearch: source filtering by values not fields

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

My documents contains a nested array of Ids.

I want to filter on these IDs (eg return only those documents where one of the IDs is 6489354).

There might be thousands of IDs, so I only want to return the source document for those IDs that are equal to certain values (eg 1, 6, or 9)

So lets say I had these two documents:

```
//IDs is a nested field
{
    "Name" : "Document1",
    "IDs" :
    [
        {"ID":1},
        {"ID":5},
        {"ID":9},
        {"ID":6489354}
    ]
}

{
    "Name":"Document2",
    "IDs"
    [
        {"ID":1},
        {"ID":5},
        {"ID":9}
    ]
}
```

Only document1 should be returned, and it's source should be:

```
{
    "Name":"Document1",
    "IDs"
    [
        {"ID":1},
        {"ID":9}
    ]
}
```

Currently sourceFiltering does not work on values, only fields. Is there some other way around this?

Comment: Can you please add exact JSON structure of your documents?

Comment: will do @SathishkumarRakkiasamy

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: It's been done. is there a problem?

Comment: It looks like what you're asking for isn't possible. Here's someone on discuss.elastic.co that wanted to do the same thing: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-es-return-only-the-part-of-an-array-that-match-the-query/10069/5

Granted the thread was a _long_ time ago. Are you programatically making that the query? If so, my best recommendation would be to filter your result there and not rely on ES to do it.

Comment: @wholevinski. I am doing it programmatically. However the results are biiiiig. i'm talking 500,000 lines of JSON. The more I can do on elasticsearch the better.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt Understood. I'm doing some more digging, but it looks like ES hasn't added support for this.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt This is promising: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits

It circumvents the niceties Elasticsearch adds to associate parent and child documents and adds more of a "JOIN" only ones that match onto the result.

Comment: Also note that this example will most likely only work with nested objects. I don't know how familiar you are with `script_fields`, but that might be a viable option as well. You could create a script field that filters out only ones that match. More info: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-request-script-fields.html

Comment: @wholevinski. innerHits would work, but it would mean I lose the structure, which will then have to be recreated, which would involve storing more structureinformation on elasticsearch, and a lot of postprocessing. I suppose i'll have to think about whether it's worth it...Thanks for the link!

Comment: @wholevinski your comments should be an answer. You have gathered some very good information about the topic, but it's not accessible in this form (comments rather than an answer)

Comment: What's not completely clear to me in your question though is what is the query that returns only `Document1` - search for documents that have an `ID` of `6489354`? Source filtering could return only `IDs` array, and `inner_hits` can give you information on the matching IDs (inner hits) for the query